# Bundler can't seem to find correct Ruby through Rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler, rbenv

For years I used RVM as my Ruby version manager, but I want to switch to rbenv for its simplicity. However I'm finding some strange problems deploying. Here's where it seems to go wrong:

```
# env RBENV_ROOT=\"/home/deploy/.rbenv\" PATH=\"/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH\"  /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --gemfile /domains/myapp.com/releases/20140119013611/Gemfile --path /domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test

> rbenv: bundle: command not found

> The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
> 2.0.0-p353
```

Okay, so I specify the rbenv version I want --

```
# env RBENV_ROOT=\"/home/deploy/.rbenv\" PATH=\"/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH\" RBENV_VERSION=\"2.0.0-p353\" /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --gemfile /domains/myapp.com/releases/20140119013611/Gemfile --path /domains/myapp.com/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test
> rbenv: version `"2.0.0-p353"' is not installed
```

Huh. That's weird.

```
# rbenv versions
> system
> * 2.0.0-p353 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? The `bundle install` command appears to think that `2.0.0-p353` is absent, but `rbenv versions` shows it. What might be up?

Comment: By the way, is this being deployed to a server?

Comment: @sethcall It is, yes. I'm trying to do this at the command line while logged into my server as the 'deploy' user, because my Capistrano deploy wasn't working.

Comment: I  guess think that's the capistrano way of doing things... it's just that I really hate downloading + compiling ruby to my server with RVM or rbenv, preferring to use a debian: https://github.com/sethcall/ubuntu-ruby-package-builder.  Mainly because it's reproducible, faster, and less prone to these tricky environmental issues.  rbenv is much more straightforward than rvm for server deploys, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  believe it's an escaping problem.

I can set the current ruby version like this successfully:

`rbenv local 2.0.0-p247`

or this:

`rbenv local "2.0.0-p247"`

But if I escape the quotes,  I get an error exactly like you get (notice the quotes in the error response):

```
> rbenv local \"2.0.0-p247\"
rbenv: version `"2.0.0-p247"' not installed
```

Note that usually quotes are not around a a bogus version:

```
> rbenv local 2.0.0-p111
rbenv: version `2.0.0-p111`
```

So, in conclusion, I'm guessing that the bundler-less system ruby is invoked in your first snippet, and you haven't yet seen a successful attempt to try bundle with the rbenv managed version due to the RBENV_VERSION quoting issue.

Comment: That's a great hypothesis, and you're right that the escaped quotes were a bit odd. Turned out when I removed _all_ the escaping backslashes, not just the ones around the version number, the bundle installed. (Or says it did.)     Now I'm getting other errors, but that's another SO post! Thanks for helping me get one step of the way there. :)

Answer (score 20):

install the bundler tool: gem install bundler.

install the dependancies of the project: bundle install

Comment: This was the hand-to-forehead moment for me after reinstalling ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: This answer also works when you run into: "The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:" if you just upgraded ruby. 

You're awesome. Thanks!