# Trouble with rbenv switching ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm getting `rbenv: version 2.0.0-p195' is not installed` when try to `bundle` even though I've installed it correctly and switch to it as below:

```
➜  rbenv versions
  system
* 2.0.0-p195 (set by /Users/me/.ruby-version)
➜  rbenv local 2.0.0-p195
➜  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
➜  bundle
rbenv: version `2.0.0-p195' is not installed
rbenv: version `2.0.0-p195' is not installed
➜  rbenv rehash
➜  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
➜  bundle
rbenv: version `2.0.0-p195' is not installed
rbenv: version `2.0.0-p195' is not installed
```

I have the ruby version I'm trying to use installed:

```
➜  ls ~/.rbenv/versions
2.0.0-p195 2.0.0-p481
```

Did anyone have this issue with rbenv? any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Load rc by `source ~/.bash_profile` and try again.

Comment: I'm using zshrc, tried adding it there without success.

Comment: @neo you sure about reload shell?

Comment: I've reloaded the shell, yes! it seems to similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212278/bundler-cant-seem-to-find-correct-ruby-through-rbenv?rq=1 still no success though

Comment: hmmmm... so i can't help you... sorry.

Comment: I solved it, I'm using rbenv that came pre-packed with boxen, just needed to include `[ -f /opt/boxen/env.sh ] && source /opt/boxen/env.sh` to my .zshrc

Comment: All good, since the problem was localized, thank you for your help!